# FB iframe canvas height

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas, tabs, height

I have a problem width tha canvas height;
I used the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init({appId: 'my_app_id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    };

</script>
```

inserted before the tag `</body>`

and it works perfectly.

But if I navigate inside the app the height is not adjusted. It does increase if necessary, but it dosen't decrease when needed; so all pages remain very tall in some situation.

From the App Settings page is only possible choose the width page tab (narrow:520 or widr:810); no settings available for the tab height.

Hope someone could help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> But if I navigate inside the app the height is not adjusted. It does increase if necessary, but it dosen't decrease when needed; so all pages remain very tall in some situation.

FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow does not decrease the iframe height, it only increases it if necessary.

And setting the size explicitly to a smaller height than the actual one doesn’t work either, from my tests.

Answer (score 0):

After all, the real problem is from facebook with http*s*

You can follow the issue here:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/live_status
```

You could also setSize, if you know it.

> FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: YOUR_WIDTH, height: YOUR_HEIGHT });

Regards

Comment: I couldn't ger `setSize` to work either... I think it is a general problem with the tab resizing and not a specific method...

Comment: put them togheter. FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: YOUR_WIDTH, height: YOUR_HEIGHT }); FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(50);

Comment: Nope - does not work.  In anycase - Facebook have confirmed the bug and are planning to push a fix soon.

Comment: I noticed, as @CBroe said, that you want to decrease height, not enlarge. Facebook documentation: "Note: when determining the Canvas Height automatically the height it can only be increased, not decreased. When possible please pass the explicit dimensions as properties of an object." I think it can't be smaller than 800px

Comment: My "solution" to you in this case would be vertical-align your app with facebook's  default height

Comment: @helmz
setSize and setAutoGrow toghether dosen't solve the problem.
actually, my app is a wordpress installation; I don't know how to retrieve the height of a page.

for lix
thanks for yur reply, I read the report bug, but it dosen't work even in http mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - there are many many bugs open at the moment on Facebook dealing with height issues.

Here is just one of them - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/394423653950625

The fix should be out soon.  In the meantime - know that you are not alone :P  We are suffering from this also... well... out clients are suffering from it and we are suffering form complaints from our clients :P